# Creating EXE of tkinter python script

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm having some trouble bundling the following python script into a single executable using pyinstaller (or py2exe or cxfreeze). I'm including only the pyinstaller code I've been trying to save space, but if anyone has any ideas to make it work with any other program feel free to let me know.

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import=matplotlib --hidden-import=numpy --hidden-import=tkinter --windowed --one-file script.py
```

I've tried variations of the above, and I keep getting a "failed to execute script pyi_rth_pkgres" error when I try to open the EXE file.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
        ax=fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8],polar=True)
        canvas=FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,master=root)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0,column=1)
        canvas.show()

        self.plotbutton=tk.Button(master=root, text="plot", command=lambda:self.plot(canvas,ax))
        self.plotbutton.grid(row=0,column=0)

    def plot(self,canvas,ax):
        c = ['r','b','g']  # plot marker colors
        ax.clear()         # clear axes from previous plot
        for i in range(3):
            theta = np.random.uniform(0,360,10)
            r = np.random.uniform(0,1,10)
            ax.plot(theta,r,linestyle="None",marker='o', color=c[i])
            canvas.draw()

root=tk.Tk()
app=Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

I know this is pretty vague, but I thought I'd throw it out there to see if anyone had any idea where I'm going wrong/what might be the issue.

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm using Python 3.5, but if anyone can get it to work with a different version that'd be great too. I've tried other versions but still no luck.

Comment: What python version are you using? There are some problems with 3.5+ due to changes of dlls used.

Comment: I was using 3.5+ primarily, though I've tried other versions (2.7, 3.4) through a virtualenv without any luck

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet that should compile your code, at least if you are using windows. As Tomasz Plaskota mentioned there are some new problem with cx_freeze and tkinter in Python 3.5, which need to be solved by custom tweaking. In all the file path you have to exchange

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5
```

to your python path.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable, hooks
# NOTE: you can include any other necessary external imports here aswell


import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\tcl\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\tcl\tk8.6"

includefiles = [r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\DLLs\tcl86t.dll",r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\DLLs\tk86t.dll"] # include any files here that you wish
includes = ['tkinter.filedialog']
excludes = []
packages = []

exe = Executable(
 # what to build
   script = "cx_freeze_example.py", # the name of your main python script goes here
   initScript = None,
   base = 'Win32GUI', # if creating a GUI instead of a console app, type "Win32GUI"
   targetName = "cx_freeze_example.exe", # this is the name of the executable file
   icon = None # if you want to use an icon file, specify the file name here
)

setup(
 # the actual setup & the definition of other misc. info
    name = "cx_freeze example", # program name
    version = "1.0",
    description = '',
    author = "",
    options = {"build_exe": {"excludes":excludes,"packages":packages,
      "include_files":includefiles,"includes": includes}},
    executables = [exe]
)
```

This code should be in the same folder as your main script and run with

```
python compile_example.py build
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd refer to this tutorial using cx_freeze. I believe cx freeze won't work with python 3.5, but I've used it for executables in python 2.7

[tutorial](https://pythonprogramming.net/converting-tkinter-to-exe-with-cx-freeze/)